# Use Strict Annotation Mode to Find Minification Bugs -- $injector:unpr Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, iis, production

### Why am I getting an "Unknown provider: e" error when hosting a production version of an Angular 7/AngularJS hybrid app in IIS?

I have an Angular 7/AngularJS hybrid app that I'm running.  Everything runs fine in development mode using "npm start".  However, after building a production version, the page gives me a

> [[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

error.  I've tried only running the Angular 7 code and that works fine.  I've tried debugging and my angularjs code in an `app.js` file is being executed fine.  The error seems to be coming from my app.module.ts when the code

```
this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app'], { strictDi: false })"
```

is executed.

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app'], { strictDi: false });
  }
}
declare var angular: any;

angular
  .module("app")
  .directive("example", downgradeComponent({ component: ExampleComponent }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory);
```

Not sure why I only get this error in production mode.  I've deployed the app as an application in IIS.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Set `strictDi: true` to get an error message that will tell which function is using implicit annotation. All implicit annotations must be removed for minification to work properly.

Comment: This led me to the actual problem and once fixed, everything worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Strict Annotation Mode to Find Minification Bugs

```
angular.bootstrap(element, ['app'], { strictDi: false })
```

From the Docs:

> - `strictDi` - disable automatic function annotation for the application. This is meant to **assist in finding bugs which break minified code.** Defaults to `false`.
>
> — [AngularJS angular.bootstrap API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap#usage)

---

### How to Enable Strict Annotation Mode from HTML

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-strict-di="true">
   <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

From the Docs:

> - `ngStrictDi` (optional) boolean
>     if this attribute is present on the app element, the injector will be created in "strict-di" mode. This means that the application will fail to invoke functions which do not use explicit function annotation (and are thus unsuitable for minification), as described in [the Dependency Injection guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), and **useful debugging info will assist in tracking down the root of these bugs.**
>
> — [AngularJS ng-app Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

For additional information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using Strict Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

On your angular.json, look at your "production" object. There might be a buildOptimizer or aot setting that might be generating an issue with the transpiled .js. I believe that the code is expecting the minified variable ("e") but at the moment of execution, the code hasn't been minified.

Comment: You're right, when I turned "optimization" to false the site works fine.  Any tips on what I should look for that might be causing this issue?  Thanks